# is there a way to force jetpack compose time picker dialog to use the clock face instead of the spinner in the UI

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

not sure how compose decides witch to show, but I have gotten different views within the same app. Seems like a bug. Surprised I see no option to force the UI into one mode or the other. In the docs I see an xml attribute: android:timePickerMode; but know of no way to implement this in compose. This is just a general question on the time picker dialog but this is my code for reference. I was not sure if it is even possible to pull xml in and use the timePickerMode somehow.  I also tried using the ignored [_ ] picker to set the option.

```
@Composable
fun TimeCardButton(
id: Int,
symbol: String,
enabled: Boolean = false,
modifier: Modifier,
onValueChange: (TimeCardEntry) -> Unit = {},
) {

// Value for storing time as a string
val timeState = remember {
    mutableStateOf(TimeCardEntry(id, symbol))
}

val validState = remember {
    timeState.value.entry.trim().isNotEmpty()
}

val mTime = remember { mutableStateOf(symbol) }



if (enabled) {
    // Fetching local context
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    // Declaring and initializing a calendar
    val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val mHour = mCalendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]
    val mMinute = mCalendar[Calendar.MINUTE]

    // Creating a TimePicker dialog
    val mTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
        mContext,0,
        {picker, mHour: Int, mMinute: Int ->

 picker.

            if (mHour > 12 ) {
                timeState.value.entry = "${mHour - 12}:${ String.format("%02d", mMinute)} pm"
                mTime.value = "${mHour -12}:${ String.format("%02d", mMinute)} pm"
            } else {
                timeState.value.entry = "${mHour}:${ String.format("%02d", mMinute)} am"
                mTime.value = "${mHour}:${ String.format("%02d", 
  mMinute)} am"
            }

            onValueChange(timeState.value)
        }, mHour, mMinute, false
    )

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
       TextButton(onClick = { mTimePickerDialog.show() }.also {  
   Log.d("click", "id $id clicked!") }) {
           // if i use just this it works
           Text(text = mTime.value)
           // if i use both of these both are set when the date 
picker is invoked
           // if i just use the second one alone, the text never changes
           //Text(text = timeState.value.entry.toString())
       }
    }
} else {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
        Text(text = symbol, color = 
  MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: To get a good answer you need to provide more information. Mainly: 
- How are you implementing the time picker (best with code snippet)
- What exactly is your problem (best with screenshots)

Comment: This is the default behaviour I get on Android 13 Emulator: https://imgur.com/a/6q2NYWt From what I understand this is what you want... So I'm not sure how to help you